# C# SQL params Insert Query not Working Properly

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Okay so I am trying to use parameters in C# sql code block but I am getting @Data in my SQL table please help

```
            string connectionString = @"Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Data Source=**********,1433;database=*******;User id=*****;Password=******;";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                //
                // Description of SQL command:
                // 1. It selects all cells from rows matching the name.
                // 2. It uses LIKE operator because Name is a Text field.
                // 3. @Name must be added as a new SqlParameter.
                //
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                "INSERT INTO [dbo].[event_logs] ([event_level],[date_and_time],[source],[event_id],[task_category],[event_data],[channel],[computer_id],[created_at],[updated_at])VALUES('" + entry.EntryType + "','" + entry.TimeWritten + "','" + entry.Source + "','" + entry.InstanceId + "','" + entry.Category + "',' @Data ','" + logtype + "','" + computerID + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "')", connection))
                {
                    //
                    // Add new SqlParameter to the command.
                    //
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Data", entry.Message));
                    //
                    // Read in the SELECT results.
                    //
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: And by the way, you are running an INSERT query, which SELECT results do you expect to get?

Comment: Instead of passing through DateTime.Now, use GETDATE() in SQL

Answer (score 2):

INSERTs don't return results.     Use `.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead of `.ExecuteReader()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `@Data` because you SQL string is formatted like `"',' @Data ','"` which is wrong, it is no more a variable, it is itself a SQL String.

What you need to do is fix the SQL query from `"',' @Data ','"` to `"', @Data ,'"` it will be fine then.

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
"INSERT INTO [dbo].[event_logs] ([event_level],[date_and_time],[source],[event_id],[task_category],[event_data],[channel],[computer_id],[created_at],[updated_at])VALUES('" + entry.EntryType + "','" + entry.TimeWritten + "','" + entry.Source + "','" + entry.InstanceId + "','" + entry.Category + "', @Data ,'" + logtype + "','" + computerID + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "')", connection))
{

    // Add new SqlParameter to the command.

    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Data", entry.Message));
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I think that you should mention that using just one parameter and leaving the string concatenation in place is totally useless.

Comment: @Steve - yes i agree to that, but i think that OP is sure that rest of data is from trusted source, since he knows using SqlParam

Comment: I would bet that this code also after your 'fix' will not work. If it works then he/she have dates stored as strings. A mistake of epic proportions

Comment: well, it indeed is saved as string!

Comment: Nothing to worry. It is just bad code, not life or death (unless you write Airplanes or Medical software)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the name and data type in the constructor, and the value in the new object:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = entry.Message;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    try
    {
        string sSQL = "INSERT INTO StuTable (Name, Batch,CGPA, DOB, Program, 
            Picture)VALUES (@Name, @Batch,@CGPA,@DOB,@Program,@Picture)";
        SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, conn);

        objCmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        objCmd.Parameters.Add("@Batch", SqlDbType.Int);
        objCmd.Parameters.Add("@CGPA", SqlDbType.Float);
        objCmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        objCmd.Parameters.Add("@Program", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        objCmd.Parameters.Add("@Picture", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500);

        //objCmd.Parameters["@RegdNo"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
        objCmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = textBox4.Text;
        objCmd.Parameters["@Batch"].Value = textBox5.Text;
        objCmd.Parameters["@CGPA"].Value = textBox6.Text;
        objCmd.Parameters["@DOB"].Value = maskedTextBox1.Text;
        objCmd.Parameters["@Program"].Value = textBox8.Text;
        objCmd.Parameters["@Picture"].Value = textBox9.Text;

        objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // MessageBox.Show("Record Added");

    }
    catch (Exception te)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(te.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```